# API not getting information

Tags: php, api, curl, hash, cryptocurrency

I am trying to build a bot to trade cryptos on Bittrex.
I have the logic figured out, but struggle with API stuff...

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with the below?

I want the output to be an array for each coin where balance > 0, where the array lists all the details in the get balances section in the API documentation

```
$apikey = "123456789";
$apisecret = "abcdefghi";
$nonce=time();
$uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/getbalances?apikey='.$apikey.'&nonce='.$nonce;
$sign=hash_hmac('SHA512',$uri,$apisecret);
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
$execResult = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($execResult, true);
```

I've tried echoing $obj, $obj['Result'], $obj['Result']['Currency'] but I just can't get anything other than a blank white page...

Comment: You can use the Postman first. Make a same request as your code in Postman and hit and check its response. May be that can help you to debug your code better.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out

Answer (score 1):

[`curl_exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php#refsect1-function.curl-exec-returnvalues) returns a boolean. For this to work as you expect you have to set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option.

```
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$execResult = curl_exec($ch);
if ($execResult === FALSE) {
  echo "An error ocurred";
  die;
}
$obj = json_decode($execResult, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Had:
$uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/getbalances?apikey='.$apikey.'&nonce='.$nonce;

Needed:
$uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getbalances?apikey='.$apikey.'&nonce='.$nonce;

Also missing:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

Thank you msg and Grimbo!